# The class name has become red when i have renamed it

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

That's it the question, when i highlighted the name of the class in the .h file, then, i go under Edit->Refactor->Rename.

However, the application is running fine and i didn't get errors or even warnings.
How can i fix it please.

Comment: Have you simply tryed closing it out and reopening the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rename by `Edit->Refactor->Rename` and if it effect the file name, you need to delete it and add it by `File`->`Add Files to 'yourProject'`, and choose the file that you've deleted.

Note: Make sure you only delete the reference and not the actual file when doing this !
Thanks @Mutix's tip.

Comment: make sure you only delete the reference and not the actual file when doing this !

Comment: right clic-> Delete, then File-> Add Files to XXX. That's how i did and i got back my file:)

Comment: @Kjuly i need to know if by right clicking the file-> Delete i am deleting only the reference or the actual file? could you please clarify this to me?

Comment: @Malek when u'r deleting a file, the XCode'll show a message for you whether u want to delete the reference or not. Maybe it'll not show when the file is invalid.